# Using bootable usb to install Ubunu 13.10: installer not finding current Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, 13.04, live-usb

I have created a bootable usb stick having Ubuntu 13.10.

When I boot my laptop, it boots from the usb. I proceed to install Ubuntu 13.10. Ahead, I get the below options.
[image: photo]
You see here the option of 'erase disk & install ubuntu'. This will delete everything on my laptop. But I was expecting the option of 'erase ubuntu 12.10 & reinstall' to appear. So, I feel that the installer fails to detect my current Ubuntu 12.10 If so, then what to be done so that my O.S is detected.

I would appreciate if one can share what options they get when they install from bootable usb ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: On your bootable current bootable USB,are you installing Ubuntu into it or you are using Live Ubuntu with persistent ?

Comment: @TommyAriaPradana I'm using the bootable usb stick to install ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop's hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try **something else** then format all the 12.10 Partition and re-use them for 13.10